# Sentry doesn't show all transactions and Web Vitals

Tags: next.js, sentry

We use combination of Sentry/NextJS

tracesSampleRate for Sentry = 0.75

Issues reports looks ok, and there are a lot of them. Really a lot.
But Performance/Transactions looks cut off.

For example, Im looking at /register route. And this high load route is really under-reported.
Here is the data for last 24h

- Home route has 9.5k
- Login 2.1k
- Register 224

Or same data from WebVitals tab

- /home - 2.9k
- /register - 157
- /login - 110 (Why so low???)

And Google Analytics (6k users for 24h):

- /home - 14k
- /login - 5.4k
- /register - 1.6k

UPD
Here is how connection looks like
next.client.config.js/next.server.config.js

```
Sentry.init({
  denyUrls: [
    /webkit-masked-url/i,
    /extensions\//i,
    /^chrome:\/\//i,
    /safari-web-extension/i,
  ],

  ignoreErrors: [
    'globalThis is not defined', // error occurs in the not supported browsers
  ],

  enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',

  // We recommend adjusting this value in production, or using tracesSampler
  // for finer control
  tracesSampleRate: 0.75,
})
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = withSentryConfig(moduleExports, {
  include: ['.', '.next'],
  ignore: ['node_modules', 'next.config.js'],
  silent: true, // Suppresses all logs
})
```

UPD2
tracesSampleRate: 0.75
Because we have a tooooons of errors.

UPD3
So proportion in events rate between Sentry and GA looks pretty same.
But amount not. Why this throttle could be?

Comment: Could it be adblockers when you visit the page yourself?

Comment: @LucaForstner was my first guess. AdBlock turned off for work env.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippets that demonstrate how you utilize Sentry? @slava

Comment: @EliasSalom, edited original post

Comment: @slava now I have a couple of questions about this,
- why do you track the error per root?
- do you try to config the sentry globally to catch every bad event happening in your server
*I think if you implement sentry with your project in different ways this will help you*